# Difference between two .tar.gz file lists on linux

Tags: linux, tar

Having two different .tar.gz files: The second .tar.gz is the subset of first .tar.gz.

I need a single line command to find the missing files in second .tar.gz.

**E.g.:**

**1.tar.gz file list:**

```
1.jsp
2.txt
3.htm
```

**2.tar.gz file list:**

```
1.jsp
3.htm
```

**output should be:**

```
2.txt
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Just list the contents and do `diff`:

```
diff <(tar -tvf 1.tar.gz | sort) <(tar -tvf 2.tar.gz | sort)
```

Comment: I get "invalid tar magic" with `tar -tvf 1.tar.gz` in bash. When I do `tar -tzvf 1.tar.gz` it works.

Comment: @FlexMcMurphy Looks like your tar doesn't support all features. Is it a busybox (which is [known to lack this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/249357/72606)?

Comment: That's exactly what it is! I'm using Busybox on OpenWrt. I'm glad I figured out how to modify your command to my more limited environment.